# Unable to overwrite method in Vue constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component with one method, which I'm firing on creation. It's using `vue-select` but purpose of this component shouldn't be relevant to my issue.

```
<template>
    <v-select :on-change="onchangecallback"></v-select>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'

    Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);

    export default {
        methods: {
            onchangecallback: () => {alert('default')}
        },
        created: function() {
            this.onchangecallback();
        }
    }
</script>
```

In other file I'm importing this component and creating a new instance of it with Vue constructor and passing new `onchangecallback` method, which, by my understanding, should overwrite the default `onchangecallback` method:

```
import VSelect from './components/ui/VSelect.vue';

new Vue({
    VSelect,
    el:         '#app',
    components: {VSelect},
    template:   `<v-select />`,
    methods:    {
        onchangecallback: () => {alert('custom')} // doesn't work
    }
});
```

But when I start the app, instead of `alert('custom')` I still get `alert('default')`.

Comment: Well first, never use arrow functions to define your methods. Second, did you mean `extends: VSelect`?

Comment: @Bert adding `extends: VSelect` to constructor made `alert('custom')` appear but `alert('default')` is displayed as well, I thought it will ovewrite it. Why I shouldn't use arrow functions for defining methods? Is it because they change `this` context?

Comment: Yes. If you use an arrow function, you will never have the correct `this` inside the method. Also, I can't replicate what you are telling me about both alerts displaying. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/RjaPWE?editors=1010

Comment: I'm quite sure what you are trying to accomplish here. I was able to replicate your issue, but if you are extending the VSelect component, I do not see the need to add the components section or the template because VSelect is the component extended, and it already defines a template.
https://codesandbox.io/s/4j2k0lvo67

Comment: @Bert It's for [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook), the idea is to overwrite component's "default" template/props/methods by each custom component scenario. But codesandbox is not replicating my issue with alert, it displays only one, for me it's two alerts.

Comment: If I ditch `VSelect.vue` and instead import vue-select directly from node_modules it works, but what if this vue-select was my own component which I'd want to overwrite? Then I'd have to define template twice as I did? Or there is something wrong with this approach?

Comment: If you are overriding the template you might consider using a mixin instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

But here is my solution https://codesandbox.io/s/84qw9z13v9

You need to define a prop to pass your new callback function to that component (through the prop)

```
 props: {
    onchangecallback: {
      type: Function,
      default() {
        return function() {
          alert('default');
        };
      },
    },
  },
  created: function() {
      this.onchangecallback();
  }
```

And the use it instead the default one.

**Check all the code in that snippet.**

Comment: but shouldn't we pass functions in `methods` property?

Answer (score 0):

For communication between components you're supposed to use events. Emit an event in a child component and make the parent component listen to it:

**In the child component:**

```
created() {
    this.$emit('change')
}
```

**In the parent component:**

*Template:*

```
<child-component v-on:change="doSomething" />
```

*Methods:*

```
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

#### Explanation

In the child component you emit an event, in this case "change", whenever something changed. In your case this was upon creation of the component.

In the parent component you tell Vue that, whenever the child component emits a "change" event, it should run the method "doSomething" in your parent component.

This is used in many places, i.e. inputs, where the input emits an event "input" whenever its content changes and any parent can listen for that by using `v-on:input="methodHere"`.

Comment: Ok, but how is that relevant to my issue?